# How can you reverse left and right speakers from a control panel?

Tags: sound

I have USB speakers connected to my Ubuntu desktop. Because of the way the cables are attached & my floor layout, I would like to reverse the left and right speaker output. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 26):

Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file and add the following lines to it:

```
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=reverse-stereo master=0 channels=2 master_channel_map=front-right,front-left channel_map=front-left,front-right
set-default-sink reverse-stereo
```

Instead of `master=0`, you may get the index or name using `pacmd list-sinks` or see the default name using `pactl get-default-sink`.

... Then restart the pulseaudio daemon with:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio --start
```

You can also omit "set-default-sink" line above and select the reversed output in the sound settings dialog when you need it.

Reference:

- [Cousjava @ ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811439)

Comment: Master may not always be `0` so if this doesn't work (as was the case for me) check the output of `pacmd list-sinks` and substitute the appropriate index.

Comment: If you prefer a simple hardware solution - see the accepted answer on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/22514/how-do-i-swap-audio-output-of-the-left-and-right-speakers

Comment: This worked, except I have to kill/start pulseaudio every startup to get the remapped output. How can I make this permanent?

Comment: are you sure you use pulse? and not pipewire? if not I'd try pipewire as it is a BIG improvement

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pipewire, a recent solution is to use "Easy Effects" application.

I have posted a solution to this here,
https://superuser.com/a/1760876/1174249

Basically after installing the application, "Stereo tools" effect has to be added from the "Effect" menu. Than swapping channels can be selected using this effect.