# How to invert left and right output | sound | bluetooth | 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

Hello dear peoples of Ubuntu,

Today I have a problem which is the following :

I'm in possession of "Beats" Headphone (IDK the exact name), and a ACER E14 (E5-475G-34VE) running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I paired the Headset via bluetooth since my cable broke, and my problem is that when I test the audio output the "Left Test" goes into my right ear, and the "Right Test" goes into my left ear.

I checked and my headphone is in the good position, and I can't put it backward because it's uncomforatable.

I tried to follow this guide : [How can you reverse left and right speakers from a control panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111523/how-can-you-reverse-left-and-right-speakers-from-a-control-panel) , but I can't  find the line wich the answer is reffering to.

Thanks to anyone who will try to help me!

P.S. : Sorry for the bad english, I'm French.

Comment: You cant find the line because it doesn't exist ... Its bad wording .. it should read "add the lines" ... just go to the bottom of that file and add those lines in .. save it .. then do the other commands he listed to kill the audio and start it again. once done you will see other options in sound control panel .. I saw the changes but couldn't check to see if it actually worked because my sound is screwed on my server and not worth trying to fix .. pulse audio sucks if you have a video card with HDMI but you don't use it... lol

Comment: lol and thank you ... you made me look into my sound issue and resolve it on my server :D hehe