# Headphone Right-Left Problem

Tags: 20.04, sound, headphones

Recently I bought a headphone but it has a stereo problem. The headphone's right side gives a left sound and the left side gives a right sound.

If any of you guys can give me the **code to reverse the right-left sound** it will be very helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you're using it correctly?

Comment: @ChanganAuto yeah R-right & L-left

Comment: I don't know much about headphones, but from the look of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331190/what-is-the-left-right-and-ground-of-this-male-stereo-jack) it seems that left and right are positioned at specific places on the jack itself.  Perhaps you can test it on another device to make sure these new headphones haven't been wired incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this (sort of) by reading [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111523/how-can-you-reverse-left-and-right-speakers-from-a-control-panel). I have to kill and restart pulseaudio every start up though, but it works perfectly afterwards.

Will update this when I find a full solution.